# Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method query(String, RowMapper<Object>) from the type JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Iam Doing my Project on Spring Frame Work. Below is the piece of code in the service class.
Hey Guys can i know what is the problem with this code??

```
List<EventCommand> employee = (List<EventCommand>) JdbcTemplate.query(sql, new EventService());
```

It says

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method query(String, RowMapper) from the type JdbcTemplate

Comment: do you have instance (object) of JdbcTemplate class?

Comment: Well, what is your question? You are accessing the method in a static way (Class.method()). You need an instance of the object to call a non-static method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create instance of `JdbcTemplate` and then call `query(String, RowMapper)` api.

```
@Autowired
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;  // use spring autowiring to autowire jdbcTemplate

List<EventCommand> employee = (List<EventCommand>) jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new EventService());
```

Comment: Thanks. The error is resolved . Thank you So much .

Answer (score 0):

`query` isn't static. You need a `new JdbcTemplate()`, or similar. Consult the [JavaDoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html).

You should be able to work this out from the error. I would recommend spending more time with the basics of Java if you can't.

Comment: Thanks for the opinion.I have created an object for the JdbcTemplate but if forgot to see it.

Answer (score 0):

First you need DataSource. You can read about it here

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqldatasources.html

Next you need to create JdbcTemplate

http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html

and use it in your query

```
List<EventCommand> employee = (List<EventCommand>) (jdbcTemplate).query(sql, new EventService());
```